# Javascript procedure to raise the z-index of an element until it is 1 above all its containing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to write a Javascript procedure to raise the `z-index` of an element so that it is 1 greater than all its containing elements (or equal to the max `z-index` if one of its containing elements has its `z-index` set to the max)? If so, how?

```
var e = $('[some selector]'); 
// ... do some stuff

// Now e will be displayed
```

Comment: When you say "containing elements", do you mean DOM parents/ancestors?

Comment: So you want it to be greater than every element within it? Can you just find it's parent element and set it to one less or does it have to be exactly 1 above its child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var max_zi = Math.max.apply(null, $('*').map(function(){
    var zi = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
    return isNaN(zi) ? 0 : zi;
}));

$("[our element]").css('z-index', max_zi+1);
```

We apply the `max` function on the z-indexes of elements (all in the page with the selector `'*'`, change if you're just looking for the elements in the element's parent container) for which the z-index is set.

Keep in mind that this method has the caveat that if an element is not positioned (e.g. it has `position: static;`), then it won't have a `z-index`, regardless of whether you set it.